# Why does this work in intellij but not eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I was looking to get the version and date information for a project I am working on. I found this site on a question about the topic https://dzone.com/articles/stamping-version-number-and

I followed the example on the page exactly while using Intellij on my computer, and the file output to the target worked exactly as expected. However, as the project I am doing this for is in eclipse, even after entering all the code in on that environment it is only printing out the template to the target folder and not replacing the text with the version or date.

I have even tried just copy and pasting the snippets out of the article into the project over the typed in code just in case I was missing some sort of typo, however it still only prints the unedited template out. I thought that since this is working on maven the different IDEs would not give different results but I can't seem to determine why it is a different result.

Edit: It appears the issue was caused by the fact that the project was recently updated to spring boot v1.3 and the template code in spring  was changed from ${template} to @template@. The version number works correctly that way but not the revision or timestamp

Comment: Does your project have maven nature? If not - go to the project menu (right click on Package Explorer) > Configure > Convert to Maven Project

Comment: It is already a maven project, I added the code the article specified into the pom and created the template file for what information of the versioning I need (version, revision, date of last revision). It works in the code (except the revision only printing out a blank line) on my intellij project, however, the project in eclipse is not one i started or am lead programmer on.   Right now just skimming the pom files to see if there may be something that is interfering

Comment: if the mechanism works using just maven on the command line (or in intellij) but not in eclipse the auto build feature of eclipse may just replaces the file but not filtering it. If you do a clean build in maven and then a maven package after (no clean) it may also be correct in eclipse. But I would assume there are some settings to enable filtering of files to avoid this.

Comment: The program also uses spring which has a pom which is the parent pom of the one in the main project. It has a <resources> section in the spring pom that has an <includes> section that lists the other files in the folder with my build Information file. I cannot edit the parent pom to put my file in that <includes> section and if i add the information to the project pom it is added to the parent but still doesn't work right.